# XAML binding to another elements command parameter

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

I have a ListBox with Items - Each item consists of a Hyperlink and a Button. I am using MVVM and Commanding. The hyperlink's commandparameter is bound to "IDForumTopic". I want to pass the same parameter from the button as the hyperlink is passing:

```
  <HyperlinkButton x:Name='hlTopicText'
    Content='{Binding ForumTopicText}'
    FontWeight='Bold'
    Margin='5,0,0,0'
    Width='175'
    Command='{Binding LoadThreadHeadersCommand,Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}'
    CommandParameter='{Binding IDForumTopic}'>
  </HyperlinkButton>
  <Button Content='New Post'
    Background='Orange'
    Command='{Binding NewForumPostWindowCommand,Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}'
    CommandParameter='{???}'>
  </Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you simply use the same binding on the buttons CommandParameter e.g:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding IDForumTopic}"
```

..or have I misunderstood your question?

Comment: That was the first thing I tried but the parameter is returning null althought the hyperlink is passing teh parameter correctly.

Comment: What happens if you set the button CommandParameter as follows: CommandParameter="{Binding}" ?  Can you also post the code for the associated command action (NewForumPostWindowCommand).

Comment: I tried that as well but nothing came back - its really bizarre.

Comment: NewForumPostWindowCommand = new DelegateCommand(OpenNewPostWindow, CanOpenNewPostWindow);                                                   public void OpenNewPostWindow(object param)
        {
            newPostWindow = new ForumNewPostChildWindow(this);
            IsNewPost = true;
            newPostWindow.Show();
        }

Comment: I'm not sure then.  Have you considered trying this with MVVM Light RelayCommands?

Comment: What I need to do is get the ListItem that contains the button and pass that in the parameter in the xaml binding. Any idea how to do that? Im not really up to speed on MVVM light yet,

Comment: Not sure where to go from here.  Sorry.  All I can suggest is a bit of detective work to work out whether the problem is down to binding or the commanding.  For example, try binding the Content property of the NewPost button to IDForumTopic.  This will allow you to easily see whether there is a binding issue.